# How do you make QTMovie full screen when played?

Tags: cocoa, quicktime

How do you make QTMovie full screen when played?

I have been trying to hunt around for a solution for this. The last response points to a document that has since been deprecated, is there an updated solution for OS X 10.7/10.8?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can set your `NSWindow` as a fullscreen window this will show your movie in full screen mode.
There are two ways to do it, one is with NSApplication and the other is with NSWindow.

To do it with NSApplication, you’ll make this simple call

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication]
        setPresentationOptions:NSFullScreenWindowMask];
```

To do it with NSWindow you’ll make this one

```
[window setCollectionBehavior:
          NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
```

There is also an `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary` that you can use to allow auxiliary windows to show up in the space with the main window.

To more details [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html)

Comment: But this just mean I can do full screen on this window, and there is more work to be done, right? It is not like iOS where you can state the movie to be played full screen and have a button to zoom in/out full screen?